# FMOD audio for my game engine

Tags: c++, visual-studio, audio, fmod

I'm working on a game engine in C++ and am using Visual Stdio 17 for the project. And for the Music and SFX, I want to use FMOD

I'm having trouble finding the correct tutorial to set it up though. I have installed the FMOD Studio API, but now need to know where do I put in the FMOD libraries.

If someone could help me or point me to the correct tutorial, it'd be nice.

Comment: I fear this is off topic here. I expect you'd get more answer in a forum or other platform.

Answer (score -1):

[FMOD setup in XCODE and Visual Studio](https://codyclaborn.me/tutorial/Setting-Up-Xcode-and-Visual-Studio-for-FMOD-Development.html#visual-studio)

Also, here's a [tutorial](https://codyclaborn.me/tutorial/making-a-basic-fmod-audio-engine-in-c.html) I found helpful for setting up a basic Audio Engine using FMOD.